# Why does my connection to a Kafka server running on Linux fail when the client is running on Windows?

Tags: python, linux, apache-kafka

I am running Apache Kafka version 3.1.0 on a Linux server (currently only a single-server setup).

The server.properties looks like this (comments stripped out for brevity):

```
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
log.retention.hours=24
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=server.dev.company.local:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=3
auto.create.topics.enable=false
inter.broker.protocol.version=3.1
```

I can connect and interact successfully from another Linux server on the network, using kafka-python:

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaClient
>>> client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers=['server.dev.company.local:9092'])
>>> client.cluster.brokers()
set([BrokerMetadata(nodeId='bootstrap-0', host='server.dev.company.local', port=9092, rack=None)])
```

If I attempt the same connection from a Windows server on the network, this is what I see (I can't even successfully create the KafkaClient):

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaClient
>>> client = KafkaClient(bootstrap_servers=['server.dev.company.local:9092'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\kafka\client_async.py", line 909, in check_version
    version = conn.check_version(timeout=remaining, strict=strict, topics=list(self.config['bootstrap_topics_filter']))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\site-packages\kafka\conn.py", line 1254, in check_version
    selector.register(self._sock, selectors.EVENT_READ)
  File "D:\python\Lib\selectors.py", line 299, in register
    key = super().register(fileobj, events, data)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\selectors.py", line 238, in register
    key = SelectorKey(fileobj, self._fileobj_lookup(fileobj), events, data)
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\selectors.py", line 225, in _fileobj_lookup
    return _fileobj_to_fd(fileobj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\selectors.py", line 39, in _fileobj_to_fd
    raise ValueError("Invalid file object: "
ValueError: Invalid file object: None
```

Similarly, if I try to create a Producer to send to the server using the Confluent.Kafka .NET library, I get the following output as soon as the code to build the Producer runs:

```
%6|1689966866.156|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 0ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
%3|1689966866.157|ERROR|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%3|1689966866.157|ERROR|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 0ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
```

There is an obvious problem with this output...I am not connecting to an SSL listener, and the broker is > 0.10 (it's 3.1.0).

I'm not sure how to even begin debugging this.

One thing that was suggested elsewhere was to explicitly set advertised.listeners in server.properties (although why that would only affect clients running on Windows, I have no idea). So I did try that:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://server.dev.company.local:9092
```

It did not make a difference.

**Edit**:

I have the exact same server setup on another Linux server, which I **can** connect to from the Windows client.

I have verified via Telnet that I can connect to the server/port from the Windows machine (it's not a firewall issue).

It seems like there must be something going wrong with the bootstrap, but I can't figure out a good way to actually debug it.

**Edit 2**:

Here is the client output with full debug:

```
%7|1690243709.297|BROKER|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Added new broker with NodeId -1
%7|1690243709.297|BRKMAIN|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Enter main broker thread
%7|1690243709.297|CONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Selected for cluster connection: bootstrap servers added (broker has 0 connection attempt(s))
%7|1690243709.297|BRKMAIN|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Enter main broker thread
%7|1690243709.297|CONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Received CONNECT op
%7|1690243709.297|INIT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: librdkafka v2.2.0 (0x20200ff) CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1 initialized (builtin.features gzip,snappy,ssl,sasl,regex,lz4,sasl_gssapi,sasl_plain,sasl_scram,plugins,zstd,sasl_oauthbearer,http,oidc, SSL ZLIB SNAPPY ZSTD CURL SASL_SCRAM SASL_OAUTHBEARER PLUGINS HDRHISTOGRAM, debug 0xfffff)
%7|1690243709.297|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Client configuration:
%7|1690243709.297|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   client.id = CLIENT-MACHINE
%7|1690243709.297|CONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: broker in state TRY_CONNECT connecting
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   client.software.name = confluent-kafka-dotnet
%7|1690243709.297|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> CONNECT
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   client.software.version = 2.2.0
%7|1690243709.297|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   metadata.broker.list = server.dev.company.local:9092
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   debug = generic,broker,topic,metadata,feature,queue,msg,protocol,cgrp,security,fetch,interceptor,plugin,consumer,admin,eos,mock,assignor,conf,all
%7|1690243709.297|CONF|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]:   dr_msg_cb = 00007FFA5ED733A4
%7|1690243709.300|CONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Connecting to ipv4#10.100.224.29:9092 (plaintext) with socket 1160
%7|1690243709.313|CONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Connected to ipv4#10.100.224.29:9092
%7|1690243709.313|CONNECTED|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Connected (#1)
%7|1690243709.313|FEATURE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features +ApiVersion to ApiVersion
%7|1690243709.313|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state CONNECT -> APIVERSION_QUERY
%7|1690243709.313|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.314|SEND|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Sent ApiVersionRequest (v3, 51 bytes @ 0, CorrId 1)
%7|1690243709.315|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY) (_TRANSPORT)
%6|1690243709.315|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
%7|1690243709.315|FEATURE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Updated enabled protocol features -ApiVersion to
%7|1690243709.315|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state APIVERSION_QUERY -> DOWN
%3|1690243709.315|ERROR|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL listener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 1ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)
%3|1690243709.315|ERROR|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down
%7|1690243709.317|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.317|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 1 buffers
%7|1690243709.318|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.318|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
%7|1690243709.318|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state DOWN -> INIT
%7|1690243709.319|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.319|DESTROY|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Terminating instance (destroy flags none (0x0))
%7|1690243709.319|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state INIT -> TRY_CONNECT
%7|1690243709.319|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.319|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Interrupting timers
%7|1690243709.320|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Sending TERMINATE to internal main thread
%7|1690243709.320|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Joining internal main thread
%7|1690243709.321|RECONNECT|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Delaying next reconnect by 192ms
%7|1690243709.320|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Internal main thread terminating
%7|1690243709.321|DESTROY|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Destroy internal
%7|1690243709.321|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.321|DESTROY|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Removing all topics
%7|1690243709.322|DESTROY|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Sending TERMINATE to server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap
%7|1690243709.322|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Purging reply queue
%7|1690243709.322|TERM|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Received TERMINATE op in state TRY_CONNECT: 2 refcnts, 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs
%7|1690243709.322|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Decommissioning internal broker
%7|1690243709.322|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Client is terminating (after 2ms in state TRY_CONNECT) (_DESTROY)
%7|1690243709.323|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker changed state TRY_CONNECT -> DOWN
%7|1690243709.323|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.322|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Join 2 broker thread(s)
%7|1690243709.322|TERM|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Received TERMINATE op in state INIT: 2 refcnts, 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs
%7|1690243709.323|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.324|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.323|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Client is terminating (after 27ms in state INIT) (_DESTROY)
%7|1690243709.324|STATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Broker changed state INIT -> DOWN
%7|1690243709.324|BROADCAST|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: Broadcasting state change
%7|1690243709.324|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
%7|1690243709.325|BRKTERM|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: terminating: broker still has 2 refcnt(s), 0 buffer(s), 0 partition(s)
%7|1690243709.325|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.325|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Broker handle is terminating (after 2ms in state DOWN) (_DESTROY)
%7|1690243709.326|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.325|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.327|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.327|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
%7|1690243709.328|BRKTERM|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: terminating: broker still has 2 refcnt(s), 0 buffer(s), 0 partition(s)
%7|1690243709.327|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap]: server.dev.company.local:9092/bootstrap: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
%7|1690243709.328|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Handle is terminating in state DOWN: 1 refcnts (0000025AA5DD5C70), 0 toppar(s), 0 active toppar(s), 0 outbufs, 0 waitresps, 0 retrybufs: failed 0 request(s) in retry+outbuf
%7|1690243709.328|FAIL|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Broker handle is terminating (after 3ms in state DOWN) (_DESTROY)
%7|1690243709.328|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.329|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Purging bufq with 0 buffers
%7|1690243709.329|BUFQ|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd::0/internal]: :0/internal: Updating 0 buffers on connection reset
%7|1690243709.329|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:main]: Internal main thread termination done
%7|1690243709.329|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Destroying op queues
%7|1690243709.330|TERMINATE|CLIENT-MACHINE#producer-1| [thrd:app]: Termination done: freeing resources
```

Comment: By default, the server only binds to localhost. You're missing `listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092`. I'd also suggest debugging with builtin Kafka CLI for start

Comment: listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 did not make a difference

also, I am able to connect from other Linux servers, just not from Windows servers

Comment: Maybe the Windows Firewall is causing issues? Or you can try a different Python version? Or different Kafka client like `confluent-kafka-python` or `aiokafka`?

Comment: I am definitely using different python versions, though have no idea why that would matter.

Comment: Your error is coming from some internal `python\Lib\selectors.py` file. [Python 3.7, for example](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1566) has issues with `kafka` library... If you want to reproduce the issue, try to minimize the differences between Python itself and the modules you have installed

Comment: One of the windows clients I am testing with is not using python at all. I have verified that that client can connect to another Linux server running that same version of Kafka (3.1.0), which makes me think this is some server-level issue with the specific server I am testing against. I just don't know how to debug it.

Comment: In the .NET client, you can configure the `debug` options  - https://github.com/confluentinc/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md